# Django - How to retrieve value of form fields before save?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

What is the correct way to retrieve the value of a field before it is saved when the model form is submitted?

For instance, I am trying to get the field 'name' as it was before changed in the form. I was doing like below, and it works, but I am not sure that's the correct way to do it.

**views.py:**

```
if formset.is_valid():
  for form in formset:
    if form.has_changed and not form.empty_permitted:
       cd = form.cleaned_data
       new_fieldName = cd.get('name')
       old_fieldName = str(cd.get('id'))
       form.save()
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`formset.is_valid` will call each form's `is_valid` method, which in turn will call `full_clean`, which calls `_post_update`, which updates the form's `instance` with the values submitted with the form. It would be too late to find references to the old values after you call `formset.is_valid`; you have two options:

1. Store copies of the instance fields *before* you call `formset.is_valid`:

   ```
   saved = {}
   for form in formset.forms:
       saved[form.instance.pk] = form.instance.__dict__.copy()
       # or keep only specific fields
   ```
2. Retrieve a *fresh* instance of the record before you call its `save`:

   ```
   original = form._meta.model.objects.get(pk=form.instance.pk)
   # compare original against form.instance and observe differences
   # save your form when you're ready:
   form.save()
   ```

Comment: original = form._meta.model.objects.get(pk=form.instance.pk) worked really well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have also pre_save(). I use is_valid to validate any errors or restrictions to the fields and pre_save to automate processes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `is_valid` calls `full_clean`, which calls `_post_clean`, which updates the `instance` with the submitted values. `pre_save` comes too late to catch the pre-update values.

Comment: Didn't know... Thanks!